# Access request or request.user in celery task

Tags: python, django, cron, celery, django-celery

I am trying to access `request.user` in django celery task function but it is unable to access as the function is not accepting any request instance, so How can I access it?

```
@shared_task
def run_everyday():
     return 0
```

I have configured that celery function in settings.py to run every day like

```
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    "run_day": {
        "task": "blog.tasks.run_everyday",
        "schedule": crontab(hour=10, minute=5),
    },
}
```

I tried by defining another function to return request as result but another function needs to pass the request already like

```
@shared_task
def run_everyday():
     user = get_request_user()

     return 0

def get_request_user(request):
     return request.user
```

It shows

> request is not defined

so How exactly can I access it? Do I need to created a middleware to get the request.user in celery task view? If yes, will that be efficient?

Comment: A celery task has no request and/or user. You run this, for example every day, so what would the user be? So it makes not much sense to access a user/request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so How exactly can I access it?

You **don't**: it makes no sense. Celery triggers a function, but there is no HTTP request involved, nor a logged in user. What would that user be? Celery just triggers a function at certain timestamps.

This is not how a view is accessed when you view a page. In that case the browser sends a HTTP request, and Django pre-processes the HTTP request, for example by looking at the session cookie and then sets a user on that request.

But that does not hold when you run a function, just when some time has been elapsed.

Comment: Okay I understand,